# Python Logging:: show logger.debug() if "-v" is given

Tags: python, logging

I write a simple script and user argparse for it. I can read the value `args.verbose` if the user supplied `--verbose`.

Now I want the change the logging config according to this flag.

If `args.verbose` is true, I want to see `logger.debug`, if it is false I don't want to see it (only `logger.info` and "more").

I don't do any logging up to now except at the top of the file:

```
import logging
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Logging should go to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

```
import logging
import sys 
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="increase output verbosity",
                    action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
if args.verbose:
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
root.addHandler(ch)

root.info(" Test Info")
root.debug("Test Debug")
```